# How to set mail attachments without saving file in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created simple application form and i was trying to upload file and send it as email attachment. And i did it with this approach:

```
class ApplyController < ApplicationController

  def prepare_email_content
    ApplyMailer.with(params).apply.deliver_now
  end

end
```

```
class ApplyMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def apply
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])

    @candidate = params[:name]
    @candidate_mail = params[:email]

    @email = @company.email



    attachments[params[:cv].original_filename] = params[:cv].read

    mail to: @email, subject: 'Hello'
  end
end
```

```
<h1>APPLY</h1>
<%= form_tag(apply_path, method: :post, multipart: true) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:name, "First and last name:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
  <%= label_tag(:email, "Email:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:email) %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :company_id, params[:company_id] %>
  <%= file_field_tag 'cv' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'All offers', hello_path %>
```

Everything was working fine - i have tested application and it was fine. Then i have developed my application and when i come back to testing i started getting this error:

[image]

On the way i have installed some gems and updated few of them. I was checking out to commit where this feature was working and it is. But i'm not able to find any differences in my code. There were some changes in /.idea folder but i don't know if any of this files could trigger this issue.

I'm using rails 6.0.3 and ruby 2.5.8

EDIT

I can see that there is a problem inside called methods. Looks like it cannot find @sort_order value and it sets data value as nil. But i have no idea how to change working of this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line you're attaching the file with

```
attachments["#{params[:cv].original_filename}"] = File.read(params[:cv].path)
```

Even though you're not *saving* the file, there is a still a local path to grab the file from.

Also, you should really consider passing the parameters to the mailer from the controller, rather than passing params in its entirety. That way if the information or format of the upload is incorrect, you can redirect back to the form and bypass sending the email.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I'm wondering if this can be conntected to some local varaibles or configurations. As I mentioned my code line was working previously but i have no idea why it stoped.